# Can i get data from 2 different kafka server clusters in the same java app?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, bigdata

i am new to kafka.  normally i write a small java demo app, set up a kafka consumer and  get data from a 3 kafka server cluster. and it works just fine.
i will set up the servers like below
 `props.put("bootstrap.servers",   "192.168.22.1:9092,192.168.22.2:9092,192.168.22.3:9092")`,  and will subscribe topics like  `consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("test_topic_1","test_topic_2","test_topic_3"))`.
now i need to consume data from 2 different clusters.

so the kafka servers will be "192.168.22.1:9092,192.168.22.2:9092,192.168.22.3:9092" as 1 cluster, 
"192.168.22.4:9092,192.168.22.5:9092,192.168.22.6:9092"  as another cluster.

and the topic will be "test_topic_1","test_topic_2","test_topic_3" from cluster number 1  ,"test_topic_4","test_topic_5","test_topic_6" from cluster number2.

Can i do this in the same java application? 
I tried but only data from 1 cluster can be consumed.
How can i make it work?  Great Thanks.

thanks @yaswanth, i did use 2 instances. Please see below my code.

```
    public class Consumer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("begin consumer");
    consume();
    consume2();
    System.out.println("finish consumer");
     }
    public static void consume() {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "192.168.116.13:9092");
    props.put("group.id", "group-test1");
    props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
    props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
    props.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
    props.put("session.timeout.ms", "30000");
    props.put("key.deserializer",         "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(props);
    consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("test_topic_1"));
     while (true) {
        ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
        for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
            System.out.println(record.topic()+"---------------------------"+record.value());
        }
    }
}
    public static void consume2() {

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "192.168.116.37:9092");
    props.put("group.id", "group-test2");
    props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
    props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
    props.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
    props.put("session.timeout.ms", "30000");
    props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer2 = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(props);
    consumer2.subscribe(Arrays.asList("test_topic_2"));     
    while (true) {
        ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer2.poll(100);
        for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
            System.out.println(record.topic()+"---------------------------"+record.value());
        }
    }
}
```

}

thanks for help, @yaswanth, it works.

Comment: You need to use different instances of consumers. Please post some code. That will help others understand better as to what is not working.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work because `consume2()` is never called. `consume()` and `consume2()` seem to be correct individually. You need to run `consume()` and `consume2()` in two different threads. You can do this. Start two different threads from you main and wrap `consume()` and `consume2()` in a `Runnable` or `Callable`.

Just to give you an idea,

```
public class Consumer2 implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "192.168.116.37:9092");
        props.put("group.id", "group-test2");
        props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
        props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
        props.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
        props.put("session.timeout.ms", "30000");
        props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer2 = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(props);
        consumer2.subscribe(Arrays.asList("test_topic_2"));
        while (true) {
            ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer2.poll(100);
            for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
                System.out.println(record.topic()+"---------------------------"+record.value());
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Consumer1 implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "192.168.116.13:9092");
        props.put("group.id", "group-test1");
        props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
        props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
        props.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
        props.put("session.timeout.ms", "30000");
        props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(props);
        consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("test_topic_1"));
        while (true) {
            ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
            for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
                System.out.println(record.topic() + "---------------------------" + record.value());
            }
        }
    }
}

public class AppStarter {

    public void init() {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        List<Runnable> runnables = new ArrayList<>();
        Future future1 = executorService.submit(new Consumer1());
        Future future2 = executorService.submit(new Consumer2());

        try {
            future1.get();
            future2.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AppStarter appStarter = new AppStarter();
        appStarter.init();
    }
}
```

**Note**: The above code is just to give you an idea on how to implement it. You could parameterize the properties and pass it as a constructor arg and have only one implementation of the Consumer class.